# Upsert in Amazon RedShift without Function or Stored Procedures

Tags: amazon-redshift, paraccel

As there is no support for user defined functions or stored procedures in RedShift, how can i achieve `UPSERT` mechanism in RedShift which is using ParAccel, a PostgreSQL 8.0.2 fork.

Currently, i'm trying to achieve UPSERT mechanism using IF...THEN...ELSE... statement
e.g:-

```
IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT...WHERE(SELECT..))
              THEN INSERT INTO tblABC() SELECT... FROM tblXYZ
              ELSE UPDATE tblABC SET.,.,.,. FROM tblXYZ WHERE...
```

which is giving me error. As i'm writing this code independently without including it in function or SP's. 
So, is there any solution to achieve UPSERT.

Thanks

Comment: Thanks for making the effort. That's much clearer; now I can tell what you want.

Comment: A link to Redshift documentation: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/t_updating-inserting-using-staging-tables-.html

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You should probably read [this article on upsert by depesz](http://www.depesz.com/2012/06/10/why-is-upsert-so-complicated/). You can't rely on `SERIALIABLE` for this since, AFAIK, ParAccel doesn't support full serializability support like in Pg 9.1+. As outlined in that post, you can't really do what you want purely in the DB anyway.

The short version is that even on current PostgreSQL versions that support writable CTEs it's still hard. On an 8.0 based ParAccel, you're pretty much out of luck.

I'd do a staged merge. `COPY` the new data to a temporary table on the server, `LOCK` the destination table, then do an `UPDATE ... FROM` followed by an `INSERT INTO ... SELECT`.  Doing the data uploads in big chunks and locking the table for the upserts is reasonably in keeping with how Redshift is used anyway.

Another approach is to externally co-ordinate the upserts via something local to your application cluster. Have all your tools communicate via an external tool where they take an "insert-intent lock" before doing an insert. You want a distributed locking tool appropriate to your system. If everything's running inside one application server, it might be as simple as a synchronized singleton object.

Comment: Thankyou very much, I have implemented the same thing, COPY to tmp table followed by an UPDATE and then INSERT INTO...SELECT. It worked.